# Hosting website on S3 from angular project won't pass initial "loading" screen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I have a large angular project containing many html, ts, and css files. I'm pretty sure my website is considered static because I have no server-side code. I am using the "s3-website" npm package to deploy my angular project's directory to my s3 bucket. It doesn't upload any of my local directories as directories on s3 but rather using "parentDirectory\directory\file.html" syntax. My index.html and error.html files are loaded correctly when visiting the s3 hosted website, but it doesn't load my angular components. For example, I have an initial "loading" screen in my index.html, but usually this is bypassed because my application's components are loaded, but in s3 it's stuck on this page. I have tried loading my entire project in s3 (with my node_modules directory, package.json, angular-cli.json, etc..) and I have tried only loading my src directory. Any ideas on how I can get my application to load with s3 hosting it? Thanks

Comment: can you pass the html loggin errors from your navigator please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Make sure webpack is installed in your angular project and run "npm run build"